# Can one Linux OS based environment application run in another Linux OS environment?

Tags: linux, operating-system, portability

I don't have any knowledge about Linux/Unix environment. So for some understanding I have put this question in front of all the developers and Unix/Linux technical people.

By applications I target IDE's used by developers, especially:

- Visual Studio
- IntelliJ Idea Community Version
- PyCharm Community Version
- Eclipse
- And other peripheral apps used by developers, gamer and network engineers

To some experienced Linux users, my question might be baseless. But consider me a beginner with Linux. Thank You in advance.

Comment: The answer depends on what you actually refer to by the general term "application". So please narrow down your question to get as precise as possible.

Comment: @arkascha ok, I'll edit the question and clear your doubt

Answer (score 0):

The term "application" is a very vague, fuzzy one these days. It does not describe some artifact with a certain internal structure and way how to invoke it but merely the general fact that it is something that can be "used".

Different types of applications are in wide spread use on today's systems, that is why I asked for a clarification of your usage of the term "application" in the comments. The examples you then gave are diverse though they appear comparable at first sight.

A correct and general answer to your question would be:

> One application can be used in different Linux based environments *if that that environment provides the necessary preconditions to do so.*

So the core of your question is kind of shifted towards whether different flavors of Linux based systems offer similar execution environments. Actually it makes sense to extend that question to operating systems in general, the difference between today's alternative is relatively small from an applications point of view.

A more detailed answer will have to differ between the different types of applications or better between their different preconditions. Those can be derived from the architectural platform the application is build on The following is a bit simplified, but should express what the situation actually is:

Take for example the IntelliJ IDEA and the Eclipse IDE. Both are java based IDEs. Java can be seen as a kind of abstraction layer that offers a very similar execution environment on different systems. Therefore both IDEs typically can be used on all systems offering such a "java runtime environment", though differences in behavior will exist where necessary. Those differences are either programmed into the IDEs or origin from the fact that certain components (for example file selection dialogs) are not actually part of the application, but the chosen platform. Naturally they may look and behave different on different platforms.

There is however another aspect that is important here especially when regarding Linux based environments: the diversity of what is today referred to as "Linux". Unlike with pure operating systems like MS-Windows or Apple's MaxOSX which both follow a centralized and restrictively controlled approach we find differences in various Linux flavors that far extend things like component versions and that availability. Freedom of choice allows for flexibility, but also holds a slightly more complex reality in the outcome. Here that means different Linux flavors do indeed offer different environments:

- different hardware architecture, unlike MS-Windows and MacOSX the system can not only be used on intel x86 based hardware, but on a variety of maybe 120 completely different hardware architectures.
- the graphical user interface (GUI or desktop environment, so windows, panels, buttons, ...) is *not* an integral part of the operating system in the Linux (Unix) world, but a separate add on. That means you can chose.
- the amount of base components available in installations of different Linux flavors differs vastly. For example there are "full fledged, fat desktop flavors" like openSUSE, RedHat or Ubuntu, but there are also minimalistic variants like Raspbian, Damn Small Linux, Puppy, Scientific Linux, distributions specialized in certain tasks like firewalling or even variants tailored for embedded devices like washing machines or moon rockets. Obviously they offer a different environment for applications. They only share the same operating system core, the "kernel", which is what the name "Linux" actually only refers to.
- ...

However, given all that diversity with it's positive and negative aspects, the Linux community has always been extremely clever and active and crafted solutions to handle that specific situations. That is why all modern desktop targeting distributions come with a mighty software management system these days. That controls dependencies between software packages and makes sure that those dependencies are met or resolved when attempting to install some package, like for example an addition IDE as in your example. So the system would take care to install a working java environment if you attempt to install one of the two java based IDE's mentioned above. That mechanism only works however if the package to be installed is correctly prepared for the distribution. That is where the usage of Linux based systems differs dramatically from other operating systems: here comes the introduction of repositories, how to search, select and install available and usable software packages for a system and and and, all a bit to wide a field to be covered here. Basically: if the producer of a package does his homework (or someone else does for him) and correctly "packages" the product, then the dependencies are correctly resolved. If however the producer only dumps the raw bunch of files, maybe as a ZIP archive and insists on a "wild" installation as typically done for example on MS-Windows based systems, so writing files into the local file system by handing administrative rights to some bundled "installer" script that can do whatever it wants (including breaking and ruining or corrupting) the system is executed on, then the systems software management is bypassed and often the outcome is "broken".

However no sane Linux user or administrator would follow such a path and install such a software. That would show a complete lack of understanding how the own system actually works and the consequent abandonment of all the advantages and comfort offered.

To make a complex story simple:

> An "application" usually *can* be used in different Linux based environments *if that application is packaged in a suitable way and the requirements like runtime environment posed by the application are offered by that system.*

I hope that shed some light on a non trivial situation ;-)

Have fun!